# android add license for 3rd party library

Tags: android

I'm creating a new app using Android studio, and I used 3rd party library as in `jar` file.

I know I need to add license for library, but I don't know how to do that.

**My questions**

- do I need to add license in code or create new license file?
- how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I suggest you to show License first time after installation of app.

Put

> liesence.txt

file in your

> assets folder

Read this file using following code:

```
String message = "";
try{
            AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
            InputStream is = am.open("licence.txt");
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                if(receiveString.equals("")){
                    stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }else{
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }
            }
            is.close();
            message = stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

And then show this message in `AlertDialog`

Comment: definitely this code will be in your Activity to show alert dialog